# iOS Objective-C: How to have both Launch xib file and static launch images in Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios8, ios9

We support all the iPhone and iPad models for our iOS application. Speaking on OS version support, we support iOS 6 and later.

As of now, we are using STATIC LAUNCH IMAGE FILES for the splash screen purpose. To be specific, we have added 13 different launch image files in images.xcassets to support the range of devices.

As everyone must be aware, Apple have moved forward with the concept of LAUNCH xib FILE from iOS 8 onwards. And they suggest to use the same specifically for iPhone 6/6S and iPhone 6 Plus/6S Plus. Below is the quote from HIG.

***"Although it’s best to use a launch file for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus, you can instead supply static launch images if necessary."***

They also tell the point that, developers can use both static launch image and launch image file in one project. Below is the relevant quote from HIG.

***"If you also need to support earlier versions of iOS, you can continue to supply static launch images in addition to a launch file."***

Keeping in the point in mind that we need to support iOS 6 onwards, we need to have both static launch images (which we already have) and dynamic launch xib file (which we need to add). **But, how do we keep both the things together in our project? And how does it really work?** Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't actually tried this yet. There's no problem with having both the launch .xib and static launch screen image in your project at the same time, and the OS will grab the resource that it needs.

Comment: Exactly @Caleb!! I have actually not tried yet in Xcode. I will try it today as you suggested.

Comment: I'm not sure why was this down voted. Please provide enough info before downvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I had to do to support both of these things in my project was migrate to the .xib file and just leave the launch images in the project.  It's easy to test that it still works with an iOS 7 device or simulator.

Comment: You mean that I should leave my Xcode assets folder as it as and add a new LaunchSceen.xib file? Didn't get one thing though. What do you mean by migrating to .xib file?

Comment: Add your LaunchScreen.xib, then in your project settings select it as the "Launch Screen File", and just leave Launch Images Source with whatever it was before.

Comment: Ok. Thanks @Charles A. I will try this.